# How to draw the normal distribution for Y|x

Tags: r

Now there are random variables X and Y which have following properties: E(X)=10 Var(X)=4 E(Y|x)=30-x/2 and Var(Y|x)=x

The question is: simulate 10000 realizations(x,y) from this model by assuming normal distribution for X and Y|x, and plot x on y

I only know use rnorm and dnorm function like this

```
x<-rnorm(10,mean=10,sd=2)
curve(dnorm(x),xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(0,0.5),col="red")
```

but how to deal dnorm(Y|x)
I am not sure this is right:

```
y<-rnorm(10,mean=(30-0.5*x),sd=sqrt(x))
```

because it show some error when I want to

```
 curve(dnorm(y),xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(0,0.5))
```

Comment: First generate the x's, then generate the y's by using the formula for y and inserting x in it.

Comment: *"it show some error in piture"* which picture ?

Comment: “generate the y's by using the formula” How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already calculated the x's and y's correctly, your issue lies in the curve function. You need to pass a distribution with parameters to the curve function, not realisations of said distributions.

In your case it is easier to plot the distributions using a histogram.

```
x<-rnorm(1e4,mean=10,sd=2)
y<-rnorm(1e4,mean=(30-0.5*x),sd=sqrt(x))
hist(x)
hist(y)
```

Comment: `hist(y)` gives you the _marginal_ distribution of Y, not the conditional distribution.

Comment: @HongOoi I believe that is what the exercise is asking. The exercise does not give us any pre-specified value of x, it says to generate 1e4 values of (x,y) and then plot them. Unless we want 1e4 plots for every value of x, I do not see another way.

Comment: Thanks, I do the same way, but I don't know why curve function didn't work